How to get references to DOM elements of a selection
I have a selection, like:
   const sel = document.getSelection();

that spans one or more HTML elements, or parts of them.
Can't find a method to get references to those elements.
The closest thing I found was:
  sel.anchorNode.cloneNode()

that returns the node's text, and what I want is a reference to the HTML node in the DOM.
Is it possible?  :-)

I think it can be achieved by using containsNodes method on a Selection object.
The general idea is to get the selection object and traverse all document elements, checking if the traversed node is part of the selection or not. Not the optimal solution but nothing else comes to my head.
function getSelectedNodes(selection) {
  const nodes = [];
  // helper method to traverse DOM tree.
  const walk = (node) => {
    for (n of node.childNodes) {
      if (selection.containsNode(n)) {
        // if node is part of the selection
        // add it to the result and stop traversing
        // on that level
        nodes.push(n);
      } else {
        // go down until you found something
        walk(n);
      }
    }
  };
  walk(document);
  return nodes;
}

Example usage:
const nodes = getSelectedNodes(document.getSelection());

Probably, if you know where your selection is, you can try to traverse a smaller tree, instead of starting on a whole document, pass there an element that you think is being selected.
